# How to prove the subtraction of limits using the formal definition?

Tags: limits, arithmetic

I have already comprehended the proof for the sum of limits, but now I have to prove the subtraction of limits and although many have suggested to use the same principles for subtraction as to addition, I have not been able to understand how this part of the addition proof would be for subtraction. This is when we substitute the $\epsilon$ for the two limits being summed by half that $\epsilon$, so that in the end, when summing everything up, we end up with a whole $\epsilon$:

$$\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon.$$

This wouldn't work for subtraction because we'd end up having zero as the final value of the subtraction, and not a whole $\epsilon$.

Comment: It doesn't matter. As one of my professors said, "It's the same amongst friends."

Comment: For addition you used the triangle inequality $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$.  For subtraction, you will use the triangle inequality $|a-b| \le |a|+|b|$.

Comment: At some crucial stage in the “sum” proof you use that $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$ (the triangle inequality). When you rewrite the proof for the “subtraction” case, the inequality turns into $|x-y|\le|x|+|y|$ where on the right side you *still have the plus sign*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you refer to real-valued functions with real domain.

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ be two such functions where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $X$.

Moreover, we are going to assume that $f\to L$ when $x\to a$ and $g\to M$ when $x\to a$.

We want to prove that $f - g$ converges to $L - M$. Indeed, based on the given hypothesis, one has that
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{1}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in X)(0 < |x - a| < \delta_{1} \Rightarrow |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}
Similarly, an analogous relation applies to $g$:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists\delta_{2}\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\forall x\in X)(0 < |x - a| < \delta_{2} \Rightarrow |g(x) - M| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

We are now able to prove the desired property: for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there correponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \min\{\delta_{1},\delta_{2}\}$ such that for every possible value of $x\in X$ which satisfies $0 < |x - a| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$ one has that
\begin{align*}
|(f(x) - g(x)) - (L - M)| = |(f(x) - L) - (g(x) - M)| \leq |f(x) - L| + |g(x) - M| < 2\varepsilon 
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It sure helps. I am sorry for not being more specific with my problem. Your solution and way of explaining the proof are really easy to understand. I was missing how to operate with inequalities. Limits seem way more complicated than comprehending integrals, derivatives, matrices, etc.

Comment: @BernardoBeniniFantin You are welcome! I am glad to help.